# VBA Function returning same result when not supposed to?

Tags: function, vba, row

I have written a function `interpolate_part_size` that will not recalculate unless I click in the Excel cell and press Enter - which then gives the correct result.  The purpose of the function is to interpolate a value comparing the current row of the active cell, with a reference row.

I have tried `Application.Volatile` but then it returns the same results on each and every row for the same argument, which is not correct.  Using F9 to recalculate doesn't work either.

Any suggestions?

```
Function interpolate_part_size(pp) As Double
'--- Subroutine to interpolate size

Dim part_size_high As Double
Dim part_size_low As Double
Dim pp_high As Double
Dim pp_low As Double
Dim low_index As Integer
Dim high_index As Integer
Dim current_row As Integer

With Application.WorksheetFunction

current_row = ActiveCell.Row
' match on the range of cells in the current row

high_index = .Match(pp, Worksheets("DATA").Range(Cells(current_row, 4), Cells(current_row, 29)), -1)
low_index = high_index + 1

pp_high = .Index(Worksheets("DATA").Range(Cells(current_row, 4), Cells(current_row, 29)), 1, high_index)
pp_low = .Index(Worksheets("DATA").Range(Cells(current_row, 4), Cells(current_row, 29)), 1, low_index)
part_size_high = .Index(Worksheets("DATA").Range("PSD"), 1, high_index)
part_size_low = .Index(Worksheets("DATA").Range("PSD"), 1, low_index)

End With

If pp_high = pp_low Then
    interpolate_part_size = part_size_low
    Else:
    interpolate_part_size = (pp - pp_low) / (pp_high - pp_low) * (part_size_high - part_size_low) + part_size_low
End If

End Function
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample excel file with which I can play around with?

Comment: There is a somewhat similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5719650/vba-user-defined-functions-not-recalculating). Does it offer any helpful ideas?